# First open program "auto restores" down after start up. Why?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have been having a situation where after booting up my Windows 7 pro computer, the first program I open will automatically "restore down" (where the programs window is not minimized, but reduced in size) after a few minuets (2 to 5) of being opened.

I have been just hitting Maximize as a work, but I would like to know why it is happening and a way to fix it.

I have tried:
Multiple programs and browsers as a test, they all get the same treatment.
Run AV and anti Malware, no detection.
I uninstalled some of the Windows updates, just in case it was that - no change.

After the computer is up an running, it does not happen again, only the first thing I open after the start up. It does not seem to affect performance or stability, just when I start getting into something for the first few mins. then window shrink.

I would like to dodge a fresh install and putting everything back if possible.

Any ideas what is driving it?

Comment: Does it do it for all/other user accounts, or just yours?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - there is only my account. No one uses my computer but me.

Comment: I was asking for the sake of diagnostics. :). if you make a new user does it behave the same way for that account?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - Ah...I will have to try that and let you know.